# What's with all these products as units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units

I've been studying physics for a few years now and I'm just fascinated by the number of useful quantities that are actually products. To name a few:

Electric potential is the product between energy and the reciprocal charge;
electric current is the product between current density and area;
momentum is the product of mass and velocity.

Is this just an interesting pattern, or is there a deeper insight that we get when we think about things as products?

Comment: momentum is mass times velocity.

Comment: Wait till you hear about fracture toughness, $K_{IC}, Pa$ $\sqrt m$

Answer (score 1):

Lets say a BB moving at one unit of distance in one unit of time has one unit of momentum.  How much momentum does a pair of BB's stuck together and moving as does the single BB have.  How about ten such BB's?  In this case we are simply reproducing the introductory definition of multiplication.

A worthwhile observation is that momentum isn't simply (rest) mass times velocity in the realm of relativistic physics. We either say that mass increases with relative velocity, or that momentum increases more than mass times velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Simple linear approximations are simple.

Consider Ohms law.  $$ I = \frac{V}{R}$$

You are used to thinking of $R$ as a constant. But if you keep increasing V, eventually something will happen to the resistor. Maybe when it's hot the resistance increases. Or maybe you get to the point that arcing starts and very complicated things start happening. So it should really be $R(V)$, meaning a function of V. At low voltages you can treat it as constant, and so get a nice linear approximation. But at higher voltages, this should not be neglected.

Another answer mentioned momentum in terms of relativity. The equation for momentum in relativity, with units giving $c=1$, is this.

$$ p = \gamma m v $$
where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2} $ is the gamma factor. For v small relative to the speed of light it is close to 1. As a linear approximation, $p=mv$ is very simple. But as $v$ gets larger, the gamma factor becomes larger, and should not be ignored.

There are many such things in physics. The leading term is linear because it is the leading term. Simple linear approximations are simple. They are often not the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to proportionality and continuity. For example, momentum is proportional to mass and velocity, so doubling mass doubles momentum, doubling velocity doubles momentum, etc, and you can deduce $p(m, v) = \alpha mv$ where $\alpha$ is some constant of proportionality that we choose to be $\alpha = 1$. Similar reasoning can probably lead you to the usefulness of electric potential, force, etc.

I don't think there's anything deeper than that as to the significance of multiplication in physics.

Although I suppose one could ask, why is our universe such that proportionality of momentum to velocity and mass is useful to think about? This leads to the question, why is our universe describable by one mathematical theory and not some other? That is, why these laws and not some other? To *that* I'm pretty sure *no one* has the answer.