# Physical significance of multiplication

Tags: kinematics, mathematics, intuition

I have a question. Hope someone helps me.

The multiplication sign in $p = m \times v$ is allowed .

But...

The addition sign in $p = m + v$ is not allowed.

It is said that in order to add different quantities, their dimensions should be the same.

My question is if quantities with different dimensions can be multiplied (as in m x v), why can't they be added?? After all, multiplication is repeated addition.

So, why $p = m + v$ is not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE. For writing equations see [this guide on Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (you just need to edit your question and add dollar signs "$" between equations).

Comment: As I ruminate [in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688954), I think multiplication ultimately comes down to statements about proportionalities.

Comment: @SongofPhysics I think we should avoid editing the equations of new users to encourage them to learn how to properly display equations and use other features of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $p = m \times v$, doesn't carry multiplication with a meaning that mass $m$ moves with velocity $v$. All we do is define the momentum $p$ of a particle of mass $m$ to be quantified by $m \times v$, where $v$ is the particle velocity. There is no special meaning to this multiplication apart from the definition of momentum.

As for $E = m \times c^2$, all it says is that energy is equivalent to mass of a particle upto a constant $c^2$. In more crude terms, this means energy and mass are interchangeable. Once again, the multiplication itself doesn't hold any special meaning.

The only difference here is that you are multiplying a variable $m$ by a constant $c^2$ whereas in the previous case both $m$ and $v$ are variables. Hence the different *meanings* by definition and not because multiplication has different meaning.

Multiplication is just a regular mathematical operation here and it carries no special physical meaning as you insinuate here. There are of course other kinds of multiplication which have different mathematical meaning such as the [inner product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), [wedge product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WedgeProduct.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Plz tell me why can't we define p = m + v.

Comment: @Curious55 From a purely physical standpoint without going into any philosophical discussion, you can prove why not using some dimensional analysis.

Comment: Do you want to suggest that 'dimensions' are always absolute and therefore we can't define p = m + v ??

Comment: I do not know what you mean by absolute here but assuming the fundamental dimensions hold as described, then your definition of momentum cannot hold if you agree that velocity is a measure of displacement over time.

Comment: If you are getting annoyed, plz don't answer further...but.      I want to ask why to define velocity as displacement over time in the first place. Why not start to define velocity by saying that the object which is moving faster has more energy or more force. If we start this way, we would work out completely new equations, which I think will describe reality in exactly the same way as our present equations do.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are just changing the meaning of the words that many people across the world already agree on. What good does that do, when as you say, the description of reality *is the same*?

Comment: I don't want to do that. I was just thinking that the equations/ laws that we have are just one way of representing things...Tell me one more thing. If multiplying mass with a rate of change is allowed, why adding mass with a rate of change is not allowed??

Comment: @Curious55 the laws we have are strongly based on experimental results and observations. There are more complicated scenarios where such a debate is fruitful when some concepts remain ambiguous. In this case however, what you're asking goes against standard intuition to obtain the exact same results. Why bother?

Comment: Thanks again...But, just tell me "If multiplying mass with a rate of change is allowed, why adding mass with a rate of change is not allowed??".... Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Because to add two quantities, they must have the same dimension. I think this is best understood with an example; If you have a rod with a length of 1.0 m, and another rod with a length of 50 cm, it makes perfect sense to say that the two rods put together (added) have a total length of 1.0 m + 50 cm = 1.5 m. We can add the two quantities because they have the same dimension. However you cannot ask "How long is 1 meter plus 25 seconds?". The question does not make physical sense, because the two quantities have *different* dimensions. In the same way, it does not make sense to sum $m$ and $p$

Comment: @ Jakob...My question is "if two quantities can be multiplied without having the same dimensions (i.e m and v), why can't they be added??"...After all, multiplication is repeated addition.

Comment: @Curious55 Yes, it CAN BE repeated addition... but addition of things with the same dimension. If you say "5m x 3m = 15 sqm", the repeated addition thing would be "(3m + 3m + 3m + 3m+ 3m) x m" which kind of makes sense, so there is no contradiction here. Also, multiplication is not IN general repeated addition. Or what addition do you see in $\pi*\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Curious55 Multiplication isn't repeated addition. That's how you motivate the definition of multiplication of positive integers to a small child, but once you extend multiplication to the real numbers and to the set of *physical quantities* (i.e. real numbers + a dimensionful unit like kilograms or meters) then the notion of repeated addition no longer makes sense.

Comment: @J. Murray... Thanks for your patient reply.....But, here we have defined p = mv, what was so necessary about multiplication here....So, my question is again the same "why can a real number + a dimensionful unit be multiplied with other such number+ a dimensionful unit.....and not added??".... "Why doesn't multiplication require the units to be same?? Is it convention/convenience or some law of the universe??".......Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Curious55 I think you should ask a separate question about why dimensional analysis allows you to multiply any two dimensionful quantities, but only lets you add two quantities if they have the same dimension. It's a reasonable question but the current question was unclear as written and I think it's unlikely you will get a good explanation in the comments. I also think you can find good answers to this question if you search for it since this is a standard topic in introductory physics.

Comment: @Curious55 I agree with Andrew. And to clarify, my previous comment was not intended to answer your question, but rather to remove the apparent paradox you mentioned. If multiplication *were* repeated addition, then the fact that addition of incompatible quantities is ill-defined would suggest that multiplication of incompatible quantities is also ill-defined.  However, multiplication is *not* repeated addition, and so there's no paradox here.